# Add UITapGestureRecognizer to UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uitapgesturerecognizer

**UPDATE**

I am creating a UIScrollView in my ViewController.  In a Drawing.m class I draw a shape onto the UIScrollView with drawRect.  I want the shape that I am drawing onto the ScrollView to be tappable.  The UITapGestureRecognizer is not working at all, it throws an error every time I tap on the shape (error is: unrecognized selector sent to instance...)

Here is how I am using the UITapGestureRecognizer:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                         initWithTarget:self.scrollView
                                         action:@selector(singleTapGestureCaptured:)];
[self.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

and the method it should be going to:

```
- (void)singleTapGestureCaptured:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
   NSLog(@"I was tapped");
}
```

How do I setup a UITapGestureRecognizer for a shape drawn on to a UIScrollView?

Comment: why not get the parent view controller (from your view's super view) and then call "`presentViewController`" or "`performSegue`" from the view controller that hosts your UIView as a subview?

Comment: Are you referring to using self.super or self.superview?  Neither of those will allow me to access anything from the superview.

Comment: The code that recognizes the tap should be in the view controller not the view, then you wouldn't have this problem. It's not the view's job to be presenting view controllers.

Comment: @rdelmar I will take that into consideration.  I tried that and ran into issues registering the UIView with a tap gesture recognizer.  Still working on it though. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The target should be `self` not `self.scrollView` unless the target selector is in a subclass of `UIScrollView`. It's crashing because on tap it's attempting to call a your `-singleTapGestureCaptured:` method on UIScrollView, instead of on your `UIViewController` subclass.